# Jenkins pipeline shell command

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have a case where multiple servers have to be deployed. I am using **extended choice parameter** so the variable ***server_names*** would be like "serverA,serverB" (comma-delimited). The code snippet for the pipeline is as below.

```
stage('Deploy Servers') {
        command = """
        for i in ${server_names//,/ };do
            echo 'starting instances - $i'
            //command to start servers
        done;
            """
        out = sshCommand remote: remote, command: command
        print(out)
    }
```

However, I am getting parsing error immediately after triggering the build.

```
unexpected char: 0xFFFF @ line , column 1.
```

If I changed the line to

```
for i in 'abcd';do
            echo 'starting instances - $i'
            //command to start servers
        done;
```

then I will get `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: i for class: WorkflowScript`

Could someone shed some lights on how to accomplish that? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try putting \ on each line of the command variable.

Comment: @PamelaSarkisyan thanks but I am getting the same error

Comment: According to the doc command parameter takes a string which looks to be defined correctly, the example given in the doc is: sshCommand remote: remote, command: "for i in {1..5}; do echo -n \"Loop \$i \"; date ; sleep 1; done" so if you put your for loop into a single line and inside the ssh command itself to test if it works firstly then move to a parameter…

Comment: Unsure if that’s helpful but try to define it as string: string command = """for-loop """ and then try wrapping the command parameter sshCommand remote: remote, command: "$command"